# Python pandas select rows based on datetime condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Here is the code for sample simulated data. Actual data can have varying start and end dates.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  

dates = pd.date_range("20100121", periods=3653)   
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3653, 1), index=dates, columns=list("A"))    
dfb=df.resample('B').apply(lambda x:x[-1])
```

From the dfb, I want to select the rows that contain values for all the days of the month.
In dfb, 2010 January and 2020 January have incomplete data. So I would like data from 2010 Feb till 2019 December.

For this particular dataset, I could do

```
df_out=dfb['2010-02':'2019-12']
```

But please help me with a better solution

Edit-- Seems there is plenty of confusion in the question. I want to omit rows that does not begin with first day of the month and rows that does not end on last day of the month. Hope that's clear.

Comment: could you elaborate on "contain values for all the days of the month"? do you mean every day in a month has data?

Comment: Yes, everyday in a month has data. So if data starts from 2013-3-13, the subset data should start from next month. It's assumed that the data is continuous after the start date.

Comment: If by "incomplete data" you mean NAN, you can drop rows with NAN values. Doesn't it solve your problem?

Comment: There is no NaN. Someone gives me this data. It starts from mid of some month1 and ends at mid of another month12. I want to subset data from beginning of month2 and end of month 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "better" solution - I assume you mean make the range dynamic based on input data. 
OK, since you mention that your data is continuous after the start date - it is a safe assumption that dates are sorted in increasing order. With this in mind, consider the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  
from datetime import date, timedelta

dates = pd.date_range("20100121", periods=3653)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3653, 1), index=dates, columns=list("A"))
print(df)
dfb=df.resample('B').apply(lambda x:x[-1])

# fd is the first index in your dataframe
fd = df.index[0]
first_day_of_next_month = fd
# checks if the first month data is incomplete, i.e. does not start with date = 1
if ( fd.day != 1 ):
   new_month = fd.month + 1
   if ( fd.month == 12 ):
      new_month = 1
   first_day_of_next_month = fd.replace(day=1).replace(month=new_month)
else:
   first_day_of_next_month = fd

# ld is the last index in your dataframe
ld = df.index[-1]
# computes the next day
next_day = ld + timedelta(days=1)
if ( next_day.month > ld.month ):
   last_day_of_prev_month = ld  # keeps the index if month is changed
else:
   last_day_of_prev_month = ld.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)


df_out=dfb[first_day_of_next_month:last_day_of_prev_month]
```

There is another way to use `dateutil.relativedelta` but you will need to install **python-dateutil** module. The above solution attempts to do it without using any extra modules.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in the general case the table is chronologically ordered (if not use .sort_index). The idea is to extract the year and month from the date and select only the lines where (year, month) is not equal to the first and last lines.

```
dfb['year'] = dfb.index.year  # col#1
dfb['month'] = dfb.index.month  # col#2

first_month = (dfb['year']==dfb.iloc[0, 1])  & (dfb['month']==dfb.iloc[0, 2])   
last_month  = (dfb['year']==dfb.iloc[-1, 1]) & (dfb['month']==dfb.iloc[-1, 2]) 

dfb = dfb.loc[(~first_month) & (~last_month)]
dfb = dfb.drop(['year', 'month'], axis=1)
```